# Using local calendar in emulator

Tags: android, calendar, emulation

all

Well, I got the emulator running on my Linux-PC (with GoogleAPI Level 8) and I installed the Calendar and CalendarProvider on it.

Then, I had to add an account, choosing between Exchange and Google. I added a Google-account, but I want to use a local calendar, too.

I didn't found any option to do that.
I tried this http://blog.stefan-macke.com/2011/12/10/how-to-add-a-local-calendar-to-the-android-2-2-froyo-emulator/
It work, but after I restarted the emulator, the local account was removed and I can't add it again, because it says, that I already have an account (Google).
I can't remove this Google-account, because the emulator says, the some Apps use it... :(

Then, I see what the App does. Very simple: just adding an entry in the Calendars-table.

I tried then to add the account using sqlite3 on the emulator with this query:

```
INSERT INTO Calendars (_id, _sync_account, _sync_account_type, name, displayName,  color, access_level, selected, ownerAccount, sync_events, timezone, hidden) VALUES (5, 'Lokal', 'LOCAL', 'Lokal', 'Lokal', 14417920, 700, 1, 'Lokal', 1, 'GMT', 0);
```

If I start the calendar, this account was removed. In LogCat I can see:

D/CalendarProvider2( 1076): removing data for removed account Account {name=Lokal, type=LOCAL}

If I start the calendar and THEN I add the entry in the table, it runs, but I can't modify an entry and the calendar-App crashed if I try to manage the calendars.

Could you please help me understanding how I can use a local account for the calendar in the emulator?

Thanks a lot
Luca Bertoncello